# Cancel Android Alarms without knowing the requestCodes

Tags: android, android-alarms

I have a `MainActivity` that starts a class `HintergrundDienst` extending `Service` by pressing a button `btnStartStop` on the MainGUI of `MainActivity` with

```
Intent inte = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HintergrundDienst.class);
Bundle ints = new Bundle();
ints.putInt....
inte.putExtras(ints);
startService(inte);
```

`MainActivity` and `HintergrundDienst` both have a

```
PlayerClass pcObject = new PlayerClass();
```

Now

```
public class PlayerClass extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ///
    }

    public void abbrechen(Context context, long requestCode)
    {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), PlayerClass.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context.getApplicationContext(), (int)requestCode, myIntent, 0);

        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }


    public void alarmieren(Context context, long requestCode, int ResID)
    {
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        ...
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, (int)requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, requestCode, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

I set alarms in `HintergrundDienst` with `audioAbspielen.alarmieren(this,time.getTimeInMillis(),R.raw.test);`.

My goal is to press `btnStartStop` once for it to start and `btnStartStop` again for it to stop all alarms. My issue is that to stop an alarm, I need `requestCode`. I'd have to put all `requestCode`s into a `List` in `PlayerClass`. But I cannot access this `List` from `MainActivity` where `btnStartStop` is directly. But I could expose it via method in `PlayerClass`. But how I see it, the `pcObject` in `MainActivity` is not the one as in `HintergrundDienst`. So the list being filled in `HintergrundDienst` might be `null` or empty in `MainActivity`.

In short: how do I cancel all alarms in this context?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreferences to save the value of requestCode when calling alarmieren, and retrieve it back to cancel.